# What's the best way to manage multiple open source projects in one project?

Tags: version-control

We use multiple open source projects in our project. We have many changes spread over these open source projects. What's the best way to manage these open source projects to keep close to upstream while living an easy life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a version control system like git to manage your forks. Be sure to track each remote repository separately. Even though they're all necessary for your final project, you'll find that separate repos make your life much much easier. Separate repos will help you manage your changes vs. remote, and will make it easier to see what's different between your local copy and the remote copy.

Even if the remote project uses subversion, consider using git to manage your local copy.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I found gclient, repo or something like that are good for us. However, it's not a perfect world.

Comment: "...consider using git" ... or any other DVCS, which suit your needs well... " to manage your local copy"